# Show that $F$ is a field

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $F_0$ is the collection of finite unions of disjoint half-open half-closed subsets in $(0,1]$, i.e. $A=\cup_{j=1}^J (a_j,b_j]$ where $0\leq a_1\leq b_1 \leq a_2...\leq b_J\leq 1.$ How to show $F_0$ is a field (algebra)? I am able to prove two of the conditions needed, see below:

1, By definition, we can take $A=(a_1,b_1]$, where $0\leq a_1=b_1\leq 1$, so that $A$ is an empty set and is in $F_0$.

2, Suppose $A$ has the general form $A=\cup_{j=1}^J (a_j,b_j]$ where $0\leq a_1\leq b_1 \leq a_2...\leq b_J\leq 1.$ So $A^c=(0,a_1)\cup (b_1,a_2]\cup (b_3,a_3]...\cup (b_J,1]$ which is a finite union of disjoint half-open half-closed subsets in $(0,1]$. So $A^c\in F_0$.

For the closure under finite unions since each $A_i$ can be overlapped, I have no ideas to show that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution to this problem will be just as "hard" as proving the following general fact:

We call a (nonempty) collection $\Omega$ of sets a *semiring* if:

1. $\Omega$ is closed under finite intersections;
2. For every $A,B\in\Omega$, the difference $A\setminus B$ can be written as a (finite) disjoint union of elements of $\Omega$, i.e., $A\setminus B=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$, where $C_i\in \Omega$ are disjoint.

(It is common also to assume that $\varnothing\in\Omega$, but that is not really necessary)

> **Exercise**: Show that the collection of half-open, half-closed intervals $(a,b]\subseteq(0,1]$ is a semiring.

And then

> **Exercise**: Let $\Omega$ be a semiring. Show that if $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$, where the $C_i\in \Omega$, then there exist disjoint $D_j\in\Omega$ with $A=\bigcup_{j=1}^m D_j$. (Hint: use induction and the fact that $A\cup B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$.) Then show that the set of all finite unions of elements of $\Omega$ is a ring.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I have done the following: Suppose $A_i=\cup_{j=1}^{J_i} (a_{i_j},b_{i_j}]$ where $0\leq a_{i_1}\leq b_{i_1} \leq a_{i_2}...\leq b_{i_{J_i}}\leq 1$ for $i=1,2,3,...,n$. Define 
\begin{equation*}
B_i=A_i -\cup_{j=1}^{i-1}A_j,
\end{equation*} Then we know that $B_i$ is disjoint and $\cup_i^n A_i=\cup_i^n B_i$. But my problem lies in showing that $B_i$ is a finite unions of disjoint half-open half-closed sub-intervals of $(0,1]$

Comment: @Terry I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to prove. Are you trying to prove that the collection of half open, half closed intervals is a semiring?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I was trying to prove closure under finite unions.